# Android Identifying Multiple Button

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, android-button

I have morethan `100 button` in my `MainLayout.xml` and i want to handle click on each. I want to group all the button and then listen to click of the group button, get the `ID` and put it into `String` and then use it as my base id to query from my `Sqlite Databse Table`. How can i do this? so far i have this on my `MainClass.java`.

**MainClass.java**

```
public class MainClass extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button B0,B1,B2,B3....;
    String baseId;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

        buttonInitializer();
    }

     public void buttonInitializer(){
        B0 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.B0); B0.setOnClickListener(this);
        B1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.B1); B1.setOnClickListener(this);
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.B0: 
                baseId = "B0";
                break;
            case R.id.B1: 
                baseId = "B1";
                break;
            ..........
            default:
                break;
        }
        QueryFire(); // Fire a query
    }

   Public void QueryFire(){
      //Fire the query with id of the clicked button
   }
}
```

As you can see if i continue doing this, i will have Long Code, i want to shorten my code, instead of the above code, i'd like to group the button and then listen of each click just like `RadioButton`, but NOTE. i dont want to use RadioButton. I'm trying to implement this seudo code.

```
// Put the button into RelativeLayout or something and use it to group the button
// OnClick of Each Button inside the GroupButton:
   // Get the ID of the Clicked Button:
   // Put the ID of Button into String:
   // and FIRE my query with ID of Button
```

Any help woul be appreciated! Thank You Very Much!!!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to specify a String for the "android:tag" attribute for each button in your xml layout, as well as an "android:onclick" attribute. This should eliminate the need for all of the findViewById() and setOnClickListener() calls.

Then, in your onClick method, you can just do something like `baseId = (String) view.getTag()`

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit of a stretch but why not use a ListView with a custom adapter? each adapter will hold a button (or whatever you want) and with every click on button you will get the id (the position of clicked element). Its far more easy on the memory as well :)